# Automatically update the scripts. ASP MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a doubt:
When publishing my ASP MVC 5 application, sometimes some .js are updated.
It is possible to prevent users from having to erase temporary data to be reflected in the change.

Update:
Solve this by using the bundles and their options.
Apparently updates the version of the packages automatically when some of these script is modified.
Thank you for your answers

Comment: You are probably asking about cache busting as it relates to asp.net mvc bundling. See [Google - asp.net mvc bundling cache busting](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+bundling+cache+busting). Do some reading / discovery and once you have a question that is clear and concise come back and ask it. See also [ask].

Comment: Use the bundling and minification features of mvc (which handles all this automatically)

Comment: I am not familiar with the use of bundle config, any address or snipp to guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in the last update of the question